# Button Label change on EVT_BUTTON in wxpython?

Tags: python, button, wxpython, label

Some system info before proceeding further:

Platform: Mac OS X 10.7.1

Python Version: ActiveState Python 2.7.1

wxPython Version: wxPython2.9-osx-cocoa-py2.7

I want the button label to be changed while performing a task

So, here is what I did/want:

```
self.run_button=wx.Button(self.panel,ID_RUN_BUTTON,label='Install')
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRun,id=ID_RUN_BUTTON)

def OnRun(self,evt):
     self.run_button.SetLabel('Installing..')
     #call a function that does the installation task
     installation_task()
     #After task completion, set the button label back to "Install"
     self.run_button.SetLabel('Install')[/code]
```

When I try doing this, it doesn't set the label to "Installing" while the task is being performed. Any suggestions how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The button never gets a chance to redraw itself with the new label because you're running your logic (installation_task()) on the GUI thread.

You need to run installation_task() on a background thread so you don't lock up the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

The "installation_task" function that you're running is blocking the GUI's mainloop. You need to update the label using threads, which means you need to learn wxPython's threadsafe methods. See the following articles: http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks or http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/